# Newly added columns is not visible for UPDATE function

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, alter

SQL Server 2008 R2

```
ALTER TABLE xxxxxx
ADD [new column] date

UPDATE xxxxxx
SET [new column]
```

and here it says

> Invalid column name 'new column'

Comment: are you sure the new column got added to the table? pls select * from table and see.

Comment: You need to first **commit** (execute) the `ALTER TABLE` - either by having a separate script that does this, or by having a `GO` keyword (used by SQL Server Management Studio when it executes your code) after the `ALTER TABLE ADD ....` line

Comment: I assume you are using Management studio. Please don't say no!!

Comment: It seems that it is an issue of the Management Studio. If I close it completely and then re-open it, the update function now sees all columns.